# JS Drag and Drop (Match) with letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drag-and-drop

I'm working with this drag and drop option and I cannot make it work with letters (match works only with numbers). Could anyone give a hint how to do it with letters?
Thank you.

© Matt Doylle

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpkQJo

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#cardPile').html( '' );
  $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [ 'a', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];


  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = [ 'a', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten' ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'string', i ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotString = $(this).data( 'string' );
  var cardString = ui.draggable.data( 'string' );

  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again

  if ( slotString == cardString ) {
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 

  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 10 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var correctCards = 0;
$( init );

function init() {

  // Hide the success message
  $('#successMessage').hide();
  $('#successMessage').css( {
    left: '580px',
    top: '250px',
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  } );

  // Reset the game
  correctCards = 0;
  $('#cardPile').html( '' );
  $('#cardSlots').html( '' );

  // Create the pile of shuffled cards
  var numbers = [ 'a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ];


  numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

  for ( var i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
    $('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id', 'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
      containment: '#content',
      stack: '#cardPile div',
      cursor: 'move',
      revert: true
    } );
  }

  // Create the card slots
  var words = ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'  ];
  for ( var i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    p=[ 'z','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ];
    $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'string', p[i] ).appendTo( '#cardSlots' ).droppable( {
      accept: '#cardPile div',
      hoverClass: 'hovered',
      drop: handleCardDrop
    } );
  }

}

function handleCardDrop( event, ui ) {
  var slotString = $(this).data( 'string' );
  var cardString = ui.draggable.data( 'string' );
 
  // If the card was dropped to the correct slot,
  // change the card colour, position it directly
  // on top of the slot, and prevent it being dragged
  // again
 
  if ( slotString == cardString ) {
   
    ui.draggable.addClass( 'correct' );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'disable' );
    $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    ui.draggable.position( { of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top' } );
    ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', false );
    correctCards++;
  } 
  
  // If all the cards have been placed correctly then display a message
  // and reset the cards for another go

  if ( correctCards == 10 ) {
    $('#successMessage').show();
    $('#successMessage').animate( {
      left: '380px',
      top: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      height: '100px',
      opacity: 1
    } );
  }

}
```

```css
/* Add some margin to the page and set a default font and colour */

body {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: "Georgia", serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  color: #333;
}

/* Give headings their own font */

h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/* Main content area */

#content {
  margin: 80px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Header/footer boxes */

.wideBox {
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ebedf2;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.wideBox h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

/* Slots for final card positions */

#cardSlots {
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

/* The initial pile of unsorted cards */

#cardPile {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffd;
}

#cardSlots, #cardPile {
  width: 910px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .3em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individual cards and slots */

#cardSlots div, #cardPile div {
  float: left;
  width: 58px;
  height: 78px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

#cardSlots div:first-child, #cardPile div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#cardSlots div.hovered {
  background: #aaa;
}

#cardSlots div {
  border-style: dashed;
}

#cardPile div {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
}

#cardPile div.ui-draggable-dragging {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* Individually coloured cards */

#card1.correct { background: orange; }
#card2.correct { background: orange; }
#card3.correct { background: orange; }
#card4.correct { background: orange; }
#card5.correct { background: orange; }
#card6.correct { background: orange; }
#card7.correct { background: orange; }
#card8.correct { background: orange; }
#card9.correct { background: orange; }
#card10.correct { background: orange; }


/* "You did it!" message */
#successMessage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 580px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #dfd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  box-shadow: .3em .3em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



<body>



<div id="content">
 <div id="cardSlots"> </div>
  <div id="cardPile"> </div>
 

  <div id="successMessage">
    <h2>You did it!</h2>
    <button onclick="init()">Play Again</button>
  </div>

</div>



</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for  you answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you are deciding the correct slot based on their corresponding `data-string`.

Here, in draggble slots

```
$('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] )
```

`data-string` value is from the array `numbers = [ 'a', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`

and in droppable slots

```
 $('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'string', i )
```

it's the index (starting from 1).

So while comparing the `data-string` values, it's working for numbers but not alphabets because in case of alphabet you are comparing number with a string (i.e. 1 and 'a') which won't be equal.

To solve the problem at hand, you could do the below for draggable section (change `numbers[i]` to `i + 1`)

```
$('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', i + 1 )
```

To solve it in general, you should use same the array as `data-string` values for draggable and droppable slots.

```
var numbers = [ 'a', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
$('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] )
$('<div>' + words[i-1] + '</div>').data( 'string', numbers[i] )
```